# Rails 5 query returns :ActiveRecord_Relation instead of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

[image]I am trying to access some specific data from the database using active records, and I am getting `<ScrapedPage::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f1c4502ef78>` instead of the actual data. I bet its something easy I'm missing but I can't figure it out.
Queries:

```
@domain  = params[:domain].to_s
         version_one = ScrapedPage.select("html").where(domain: @domain ,created_at: params[:version_one]).to_s
         version_two = ScrapedPage.select("html").where(domain: @domain ,created_at:params[:version_one]).to_s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find_by` instead of `where`.

`where` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `find_by` returns only one record.

If your request will return one record, you can use `where` with `first` like the below:

```
version_one = ScrapedPage.select("html").where(domain: @domain, created_at: params[:version_one]).first
```

`version_one` is a relation object, you can access the `html` data like the below:

```
version_one.html
```

You can see result of the query with both `find_by` and `where` the below.

[image]

Comment: I've replaced `where` with `find_by` and I get the same thing  even if I use `.first`. Not entirely the same thing but this `<ScrapedPage:0x00007f1c45e4b728>`

Comment: @Padu Show me query with `.first`

Comment: `` version_one = ScrapedPage.select("html").where(domain: @domain, created_at: params[:version_one]).first
    version_two = ScrapedPage.select("html").where(domain: @domain ,created_at: params[:version_two]).first``  Here you go

Comment: @Padu I have ran the query with both `find_by` and `where` and I put the result into the answer. I think you should track the console with `inspect` method for more detail.

Comment: I have tried running it from the console like this and it works `version_one = ScrapedPage.select("html").find_by(domain:'test1', created_at: '1990-01-01 00:00:01 UTC')
=> #<ScrapedPage id: nil, html: "<div class=\"diff\"> <ul> <li class=\"del\"><del>Hello...">` so I'm thinking it might be something wrong with my params. This is the  [StackTrace](https://imgur.com/a/b1O36) with `.find_by`.

Comment: Maybe. You can track the params with `puts` at the console. Also for making more easily the tracking in the console, you can use `colorize` gem. https://github.com/fazibear/colorize @Padu

Comment: I have added a screenshot of a trace on my question. Let's continue this in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165441/discussion-between-padu-and-hamdi).